# multiple applications that share one database in C#

Tags: c#, database, dataset, share

i've made an application (winform - C# - .Net 3.5) this application use a database, i want to install this applications on a LAN and make all the aplications share one same database, i have no idea how to do that, so can you help ? thxx

Comment: How about storing connection string in app.config and copy it over to all machines?

Comment: Specifying what DB server your are using (MS SQL, MS SQL CE, MySQL,Access, Oracle...) would help to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Choosing a ClickOnce Deployment Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98bcab65-ab8b-4ed1-9adc-fdacf92b8106%28v=vs.90%29)

Comment: in fact ! i used a Dataset build from the wizard, but since my application will be installed on many LAN computers and the database has to be shared, the connection string will change... so i'm digging for a way to change it from the App.config file...! i'll let you know if i need help